# MySQL junction table query with or without junction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've got some major tables and a junction table which link a couple of the tables together in MySQL. The first major table is `contacts`, the 2nd is `addresses` and the 3rd is `categories`. The junction tables are `contact_address` which links `contacts` and `addresses` using their `contact_id` and `address_id` primary keys. I need to get the contacts with or without addresses which belong to a category called `plumber`...

I've currently got this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    contacts T1
JOIN
    contact_categories T2
USING
    (contact_id)
JOIN
    contact_address T3
USING
    (contact_id)
JOIN
    addresses T4
ON
    T3.address_id = T4.address_id
WHERE
    T2.general = 'Plumber'
```

Which works fine as long as the Plumber has an address, but what about the homeless plumbers... where are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a LEFT JOIN instead of an (INNER) JOIN:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    contacts T1 JOIN contact_categories T2
    USING (contact_id)
    LEFT JOIN
    contact_address T3
    USING (contact_id)
    LEFT JOIN
    addresses T4
    ON T3.address_id = T4.address_id
WHERE
    T2.general = 'Plumber'
```

An INNER JOIN returns all rows where the join operation succeeds, a LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the LEFT table, and the rows from the right table where the join succeeds, or all NULL values for the right table when the join does not. Please have a look at this [visual explanations of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: Great resource that link